# Mount network share on boot with hidden password

Tags: raspbian, networking, linux, pi-4, password

When I was trying to mount a network share on boot by adding the following line to the /etc/fstab file:

```
//<server>/folder  /home/pi/target  cifs username=<username>,password=<password>,nofail,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.requires=network-online.target,x-systemd.automount,vers=3.0  0 0
```

I noticed that I have to put my password there in plain text. So I was just wondering if it was possible to hide the password or encrypt it in the way that the system can read it. Any help, much appreciated.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/436178/how-to-use-a-credential-file-when-mounting-a-samba-share-using-mount-command

Answer (score 0):

Try Python utility `cifscloak`.

```
sudo pip3 install cifscloak
```

https://github.com/sudoofus/cifscloak

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/113585)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).